# Magento 2 optimize JS?

Tags: page, pagespeed, pagespeed-insights, gtmetrix

I have been optimizng magento store and faced that there are around 148 scripts running when homepage is loading so I did default Magento bundle enabled and then total number of elements requesting the server were reduced to 24 but then the problem was the page size was increased to 3.44 MB which is huge so I disabled it 
How can I optimize it???
I am done with default magento optimize tips 
minify css js optimize image and flat category 
alsp have installed magento extension 
Defer JS

[image: gtmetrix]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Magento 2 Store Optimization?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/310957/magento-2-store-optimization)

Comment: I have done these steps but still no result

Answer (score 2):

You can try magento baler for bundling your js.

Please see and follow below links.

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/performance-best-practices/advanced-js-bundling.html

https://www.integer-net.com/magento-2-javascript-bundling-baler-devtools/

Thank you