# Magento 2 Store Optimization?

Tags: magento2, optimization, pagespeed, gtmetrix

I want to optimize magneto store.

Magento store is deployed on Aws. I have not installed SSL certificate yet because It is still in development phase so I have not mapped it with domain name it is an IP address
I have enabled default minify , merge and bundle JS &CSS , done with all necessary steps like optimize images , enable flat category , enable g-zip compression After perform all steps my loading is reduced from 14 seconds to 6 seconds but I want to optimize it more to 3 seconds at least???

Also before enabling merge ., minify and bundle JS the total number of requests were 224 so I decided to enable it and it is reduced to 24.

[image: gtmetrix]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In you question, which page is not defined so assuming homepage.

You have used bundle here so assuming you have already enabled all cache tags and production mode.

Other then that you can try these,

- varnish caching @ https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/config-guide/varnish/config-varnish.html
- using redis for caching @ https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/config-guide/redis/redis-pg-cache.html
- using memcache for session storage @ https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/config-guide/memcache/memcache.html

If you are looking for PLP, then using elasticsearch helps a lot.

and there are other ways to optimize magento store. You can try dev:profiler or other tools to see more in-depth code execution time to really optimize, refactor code.

PS: you seems like talking about loading time that may be frontend or backend as well. do check TTFB, API, assets, JS load time due to KO.